# Linkedin Javascript SDK - Setting the SDK Domains in the app configuration page has no effect

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

No matter how hard I try, and no matter the url format I'm giving in the  `Setting the SDK Domains` section of the Linkedin Javascript SDK, I keep getting this error in my console:

`Uncaught Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration.`

My setup it's as simple as possible :

    `<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key:afyXZGKtvrVoXXXX
    </script>`

I've tried all the URL variations in the SDK Domains section:

- having localhost with and without port ( http://localhost:9000 )
- having a custom hostname with and without port ( http://dev.local:9000 )
- having a real existing domain name ( heroku app ) (http://somename.herokuapp.com)

Nothing worked, keep getting the same error.

Any advice appreciated.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key:afyXZGKtvrVoXXXX
        authorize: true
 </script>
```